# OSMdroid pathoverlay different colors for segments

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm drawing a path on OSM map, using OSMdroid pathoverlay. Thing that I want is to give different colors to path segments. For example green color between first and second points, red - between second and third, etc. Is there a simple way to do that or I just have to draw path for each two points. Here is my code:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setAlpha(90);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(10); 

final PathOverlay myPath = new PathOverlay(Color.RED, this);
myPath.setPaint(paint);

GeoPoint pt0 = new GeoPoint(55.50751471753, 37.573947718445);
GeoPoint pt1 = new GeoPoint(55.515894950325, 37.576943422821);
GeoPoint pt2 = new GeoPoint(55.558540269411, 37.589379590206);
GeoPoint pt3 = new GeoPoint(55.560980447657, 37.58950603316);
GeoPoint pt4 = new GeoPoint(55.563488028278, 37.583155265129);
GeoPoint pt5 = new GeoPoint(55.566675052453, 37.574270957266);

myPath.addPoint(pt0);
myPath.addPoint(pt1);
myPath.addPoint(pt2);
myPath.addPoint(pt3);
myPath.addPoint(pt4);
myPath.addPoint(pt5);
mMapView.getOverlays().add(myPath);
```

Comment: You can extend the overlay or pathOverlay class and have an inside member to hold the value of color, everytim you want to change the color you can just retrieve that object and change.

Answer (score 0):

late to answer, but for others who are looking for a solution to create a `multicolor polyline in osmdroid`:

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Polyline-advanced-display-styles